# For api call I want to create middelware service in angular 2

Tags: angular

For different api call I want to create one middelware service in angular 2 which handle api response, if response expect from 200 page redirect to login.

Comment: based on response you want to load the page? like catching unauthorised calls in catch and redirect. many examples available for it.

Comment: sure you can... whats the issue... did you try coding it?

Comment: You can use an interceptor, https://medium.com/aviabird/http-interceptor-angular2-way-e57dc2842462

Comment: I have no idea so I ask here and before that I tried to find out but I did not get so.. If you have any link then please give me.. thanks.. @ JayDeeEss ,  k11k2